# How to write an trigger to update uniqueidentifier field?

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I am using SSMS 2008 and am trying to write a trigger now to update a uniqueidentifier field after an insert.  How do I do this?  Example data is below:

```
c1                               c2   c3   c4
xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx              A    BB  C5
xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx              A2   BB  C
xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx              A3   BB  C7
xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx              A4   BB  C
```

The table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.rd_information3_cleaned (
c1 uniqueidentifier NULL,
    c2 nvarchar(50),
    c3 nvarchar(50),
 c4 nvarchar(50)
)
```

So I want "c1" to automatically be updated to uniqueid after inserting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the default value of that column. NewId() will generate a new Guid for you.

Here's a screen cap for the designer. [image]